# Problem with node-gyp on windows: configure error

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, bcrypt, node-gyp

I want to install the bcrypt package for node, but I have problems with node-gyp.

I have the "Visual Studio Build Tools 2017" installed (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools`), aswell as Python 2.7.16 (`C:/Python27/python.exe`)

Full console output:

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.6/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.6-node-v72-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.6 and node@12.4.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 16, in <module>
    sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
  File "X:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 545, in script_main
    return main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "X:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 538, in main
    return gyp_main(args)
  File "X:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 514, in gyp_main
    options.duplicate_basename_check)
  File "X:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 98, in Load
    generator.CalculateVariables(default_variables, params)
  File "X:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 1916, in CalculateVariables
    generator_flags.get('msvs_version', 'auto'))
  File "X:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\MSVSVersion.py", line 434, in SelectVisualStudioVersion
    versions = _DetectVisualStudioVersions(version_map[version], 'e' in version)
KeyError: '2017'
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (X:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "X:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "X:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=X:\\code\\toDoList\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding\\bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=X:\\code\\toDoList\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72" "--python=c:\\Python27\\python.exe" "--msvs_version=2017"
gyp ERR! cwd X:\code\toDoList\node_modules\bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v12.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'X:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe X:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=X:\code\toDoList\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=X:\code\toDoList\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72 --python=c:\Python27\python.exe --msvs_version=2017' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (X:\code\toDoList\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "X:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "X:\\code\\toDoList\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd X:\code\toDoList\node_modules\bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.4.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN todolist@0.1.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-06-21T15_27_23_192Z-debug.log
```

I want to use bcrypt in my node project, it works on Arch but not on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure what I have done, but this fixed it for me.

I uninstalled

- NodeJS
- Everything in the Visual Studio Installer

I removed every refrence to npm/node I could find (%appdata%/npm, %temp%)
reinstalled Node, installed node-gyp via `npm install -g node-gyp` & `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`. Still didn't work.

But then I installed Visual Studio 2019 and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Run Git Bash as Adminstrator

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools node-gyp
PYTHON='C:\\Users\\[YOUR USER]\\.windows-build-tools\\python27\\python.exe'
export PYTHON
npm config set PYTHON
```

If you want to use command prompt, you need to use the equivalent of "export".

Comment: I see that you too, came across this post: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1842 Unfortunately, the command installs python under C:/Python27 for me and after setting the PYTHON environment variable I still get the same error, that it could not be executed.

Comment: If I move the folder Python27 to windows-build-tools manually and let the environment variable point there, node-gyp still looks under C:\python27 and gives me the error it couldn't find python there (upon running npm install).

Comment: @Phil When I worked on this the build tools were installed in the path I mentioned. However, if it installed to a different location for you, you just need to update the 2nd line and you are set. If it looks in other location that the ones you specified, make sure you don't have other vars with the same name on your machine.

Comment: actually it worked now. The problem was that the installation automatically the python path in the global .npmrc (in the appdata/roaming/npm/etc folder). So setting it manually to the one in windows-build-tools requires doing so in windows environment variables (or bash_profile) and removing it from the npm config.

The global npm config can be found with this command: `npm config get globalconfig`